# Does this work with void *pointers? If not, how?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, void, void-pointers

In our code we have a big struct of mixed types, and want to store a duplicate (const) struct of default values for these.

When the user want to default a setting, it would be nice to be able to do this by just taking the address offset of the item within the struct, and then assign the value with the same offset in the "defaults" struct, a bit like this:

```
void *setting = &settings->thing; // Points to a setting
int offset = setting - &settings;
void *default = &defaults_struct + offset; // Points to the default value
*setting = *default; // Set setting to default value
```

The idea being that if settings->thing points to an int8, the int8 value is copied from defaults, but if settings->other_thing is an int32, the full 32-bits are copied over.

The question is, does this work with void pointers as I've described above? If not, is there a way of doing this? Am I missing a better way of achieving this?

Edit to clarify: We want to set a single value within the struct to the corresponding value within the "defaults" struct.

Comment: Why not just `settings->thing = defaults_struct->thing`?

Comment: You can't do pointer arithmetic on void pointers, nor can you copy anything through it like that. You'll need to use `char*` and figure out the appropriate length to copy (and do the copy yourself).

Comment: You should use the `offsetof` macro to compute an offset.

Comment: @interjay, probably you mean `settings->thing = defaults_struct.thing`?

Comment: @interjay - in the bigger picture, the setting being modified would just be passed to us as a pointer:
make_default(void *setting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this doesn't work. Pointers of type `void *` don't have a size associated with them, i.e. it's unknown what data type they point at. It follows that you can't do the assignment like that, either.

You should probably just copy from the defaults directly, as suggested in a comment.

Also note that `default` is a reserved word in C, so you shouldn't use it for a variable.

If the defaults are globally visible, you might define a macro to hide this:

```
#define INITIALIZE(s, f) s. f = default_struct. f
```

The user (which I assume is a developer) can now do:

```
struct settings s;

INITIALIZE(s, thing);
```

That said, I would (as a developer) prefer something like:

```
struct settings s = get_default_settings();
```

This is more clear, and less magic. Sure, it probably takes more time to copy *all* the fields, but settings are generally not performance-critical.

Note that the above function might just be:

```
struct settings get_default_settings(void)
{
  static const struct settings the_defaults = {/* the default values go here*/};

  return the_defaults;
}
```

Which neatly encapsulates the default values, and removes the global.

Comment: I can see that copies the ENTIRE struct, I want to just set ONE value from the struct while leaving the rest alone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in type/reflection information for runtime in C. In order to do what you requested, you'd need to know at runtime the actual size of the type you're copying.

If you really want to do what you're doing, you need to define your own runtime type information, generally by making each setting a structure of its own.. something like...

```
struct single_setting {
 int stype;
 union {
  uint8_t s8;
  uint16_t s16;
  uint32_t s32;
  uint64_t s64;
  struct {
   char *s;
   size_t len;
  } sstr;
 } u_value;
};
```

And then writing a function to copy and return such a value becomes fairly simple.

This is quite some overhead if all you want is to copy a few settings, but is pretty much what large configuration systems do.

Comment: Thanks, adding metadata for each setting is something I've been toying with but does add a fair overhead on an embedded system, especially as ours is already established (fair codebase that would need updating).

I like the style of having a "setting type" struct for each setting.